# How to include a php file from parentdomain?

Tags: php, include, subdomain

I am trying to include a PHP file from a parent domain in a subdomain.

In subdomain.parentdomain.com/test.php I have

```
include ('/var/www/vhosts/parentdomain.com/website/wp-blog-header.php');
```

My subdomain looks like

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] gives /var/www/vhosts/parentdomain.com/subdomain.parentdomain.com
```

I have server access with plesk 11, but I don't know which PHP setting I have to change to enable including files from parent domain? Should I edit php_settings-> include_path setting and add /var/www/vhosts/parentdomain.com as path?

I have tried

```
ini_set("include_path","/var/www/vhosts/parentdomain.com/website/");
require "wp-blog-header.php";
```

Comment: This might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021000/use-external-class-file-from-parent-domain-onto-subdomain

Answer (score 0):

almost working.

This one

```
ini_set("include_path","/var/www/vhosts/parentdomain.com/httpdocs/website/");
require "wp-blog-header.php";
```

seems to work when i call wordpress function bloginfo

```
echo bloginfo('stylesheet_url').'<br/>';
echo bloginfo('name').'<br/>';
```

but wordpress functions like get_the_title() doesn't work?